# How to verify method is called with specific arguments once, but ignore calls with other arguements?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have a method that I am trying to verify is called once with specific arguments, but I don't care if the method is called any other number of times with different arguments. How can I do this in Mockito.

For example:

```
obj.method("example", example); // expected
obj.method("example1", example2); // indifferent  
obj.method("example", example); // unexpected  

verify(obj).method("example", example); // will pass
```

Comment: I would not expect `example2` to have any influence on your verify there, **unless** `example.equals(example2)`. For example, assume `x.doSomething("a"); x.doSomething("b");` -> `Mockito.verify(x).doSomething("a");` - works, while if we added `x.doSomething(new String("a");` it would not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
verify(obj).method("example", example); // will pass
```

The indifferent code will not cause verify to fail.

My issue was that the expected line was not being executed and the indifferent showed up as different from what was expected after the unit test ran. Causing me to believe the expected line ran and the indifferent line to cause the failure.